# How to get node name without namespace if it exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, minidom

I have an xml, from which i need to parse some node names, but it is with namespaces, ir it possible somehow to remove it? For example :

```
XAddr = response.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'XAddr')

for addr in XAddr:
    print addr.parentNode.tagName
```

Prints:

```
tt:Device
tt:Events
tt:Imaging
tt:Media
tt:PTZ
```

i need to remove `tt:`, but it also may not exists or exists something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split a tag name from (optional) namespace; take the last part.

```
>>> 'tt:Device'.split(':')[-1]  # with namespace
'Device'
>>> 'Device'.split(':')[-1]  # without namespace
'Device'
```

---

Replace following:

```
addr.parentNode.tagName
```

with:

```
addr.parentNode.tagName.split(':')[-1]
```